# Recaulculate element height

Tags: jquery

I'm using [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) plugin to create a fixed div on scroll.

This is how I'm using it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sticky').scrollToFixed({marginTop: $('.site-header').outerHeight()});
});
```

The problem is that `outerHeight` changes dynamically with jQuery, and I would like to recalculate the new `outerHeight` before firing `scrollToFixed`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you have a callback function for when the `.site-header`'s height changes you can remove the scrollToFixed element using the `detach` method: `$('.sticky').trigger('detach.ScrollToFixed');` and attach it again.

Comment: The documentation says that `marginTop` also accepts a function; have you tried it that way?

Comment: @Stryner, I'm already using this: `$('.site-header').outerHeight()`. What other functions you're referring to?

Comment: I mean doing something like `marginTop: function() { return $('.site-header').outerHeight() }`

Comment: Yes, but `$('.site-header').outerHeight()` is only calculated at `$(document).ready()`, right? Can I recalculate if after say I scroll 100px?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but set the css attribute first, then apply the scrollToFixed:

```
    $('.sticky').css('margin-top',$('.site-header').outerHeight()).scrollToFixed();
```